# Passing PHP form data into a HTML page

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

The following is the PHP code to my login script:

```
   <?php

session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];



            $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "test");
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
                echo mysqli_connect_error();
            } 

            $query = "SELECT * FROM members where username = '$username'";

            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        $log = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $dbusername=$log['username'];
        $dbpassword=$log['password'];
        //echo "<h1> ". $log['username']." ".$log['password']."</h1>";
        if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword)
        {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $dbpassword;
            header("Location: Correct.html {$_POST["redirect"]}"); 
        }else
        {
            header("Location: Incorrect.html {$_POST["redirect"]}"); 
        }

} else {
    echo "boo";
}

    ?>
```

As you can see, the user is redirected to the 'Correct.html' page should they enter an existing username and password combination. The problem is passing information onto the 'Correct.html' page. I would like the '**username**' variable to be passed-on so that the page will show a "**Welcome 'username'**" message. Now from all my attempts I am aware that I need the following piece of code on the 'Correct.html' page for this variable to be successfully passed through:

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Your session is running " . $_SESSION['username'];
}
?>
```

I have also found out that for this to work, I need to change the extension of my page from .HTML to .PHP. Now the problem is that if I change the extension, my 'Correct.php' page will no longer load, and I am shown a blank screen. I have tried online HTML to PHP converters (which seem to echo every line of my code), but this still does not work.

Would anyone be able to help me on one of two things:

1. Provide me a solution to passing through a PHP variable in a HTML script (easier, but not sure if possible?)
2. Correctly convert my HTML code to PHP (longer, but would ensure that variables can easily be passed through)

Please bear in mind that I already have a MySQL database and table setup (you probably already figured that from the code).

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** use string interpolation with `$_POST` parameters.

Comment: don't you get errors here -> `"{$_POST["redirect"]}"` ?

Comment: Have you tried javascript to intercept the value? That way you wouldn't need the PHP.  There is an example here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609511/javascript-url-parameter-parsing

Comment: @tadman I am not sure what you mean at all. Would you be able to provide me with a written example please?

Comment: @vp_arth I do not. At the moment I am redirected to the page I want (however this also works if {$_POST["redirect"]} is removed). Should I remove this?

Comment: @user3486733. not, I'm just surprised that it works, I thought I needed inside single quotes :)

Comment: @durbnpoisn I am not too sure what I'm looking for in your link. Would you be able to provide a written example please?

Comment: @AKJ9 You're throwing `$_POST['username']` and other data **directly** into your query without escaping. This is super dangerously bad. You absolutely must escape that, and the best way to do that is with placeholders like `?` and the `bind_param` method which replaces those, safely, with the correct data. More links in my original comment.

Comment: @tadman right, so how do I integrate placeholders and blind_param into my scripts? Apologies for the questions, as I've said (now been removed), I am a rookie with this and would need a clear explanation of what to do and why it works, if you're willing to do so!

Comment: @AKJ9 The [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) documentation has a lot of examples at the bottom. Check them out.

Answer (score 0):

The extension of the file names don't matter if you set your web server correctly.  If it's Apache HTTP: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html`, or something like it.

`header()` expects a full URI.  So pass in the domain name and path along with the file name.  And get rid of the `{$_POST["redirect"]}` stuff in the header calls (not sure what you were trying to do with that).

Comment: Hi, I've seen this 'AddType' line before and tried inserting it into my code. Apologies, I am not very experienced with this and am not too sure if my web server is Apache HTTP. How do I find out? Would telling you that I use phpmyadmin help at all? What would you advise?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just provide it as an answer with an explanation...

Here is the [example answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609511/javascript-url-parameter-parsing) I cited.
What it does is looks at the URL that was sent to the browser, searches for a "?", which would imply there is a parameter being passed.  It then grabs everything after the "?" and splits it at the "&"s to provide for all the parameters that were passed.  It then loops through what it finds, and creates a list of what was passed in.  Like, "username=bob", "thissite=spiffy".

You can use this in any HTML file to handle parameters passed in.  There is no need for the server side scripting like PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really sorry, I've had a look through and can't seem to identify what applies to my code. What Javasript do I need for intercepting the value?